# How to test function returns IEnumerable<Integer>

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, ienumerable

I'm trying to test a function

```
public static IEnumerable<Integer> Divisors(Integer n)
{
    int max = (int)System.Math.Sqrt(n);

    if (n != 0)
        yield return 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            yield return i;
}
```

and I need to write a test function like

```
[Test]
public void DivisorsTest()
{   
    Integer n = 0; 
    IEnumerable<Integer> expected = 0 ; //error
    IEnumerable<Integer> actual;
    actual = Science.Mathematics.NumberTheoryFunctions.Divisors(n);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

How can I modify this line to test the output I need to test the returning values which are not just a zero

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, a well-written (and well-formatted) question that doesn't demand an answer "AS SOON AS POSSIBLE" will be received much more favorably.

Comment: BTW, which UT framework are you using? NUnit, VS unit tests?

Comment: please, would you tell me how to add another tag for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks everybody for your answers and here is what i did using your answers

the test functions will be :
1- when you expect that the function won't return any value

```
[Test]
   public void DivisorsTest_01()
   {   
       Integer n = 0; 
       IEnumerable<Integer> actual;
       actual = Science.Mathematics.NumberTheoryFunctions.Divisors(n);
       Assert.IsFalse(actual.Any()); // There should not be any elements returned so empty
   }
```

2- all what you need is to convert the o/p into an array and use it :

```
[Test]
   public void DivisorsTest_03()
   {
       Integer n = 9;
       Integer[] expected = new Integer[3] { 1,3,9 };
       IEnumerable<Integer> actual;
       actual = Science.Mathematics.NumberTheoryFunctions.Divisors(n);
       var actual1 = actual.ToArray();

       Assert.AreEqual(expected[0], actual1[0]);
       Assert.AreEqual(expected[1], actual1[1]);
       Assert.AreEqual(expected[2], actual1[2]);

   }
```

3- sometimes you expect the output will be exception so don't forget to write:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException]
```

before the function.

thanks again everybody

Answer (score 2):

There are various tricks to checking entire collections. It looks like for an input of zero, you don't want to have any values returned (i.e. an empty set), so you could do this:

```
Assert.IsFalse(actual.Any()); // There should not be any elements returned
```

For more complex outputs, it is often easier to put the result into an array, and check the results by index like this:

```
var results = actual.ToArray();
Assert.AreEqual(5, results.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(1, results[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(2, results[1]);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use something like this (sorry, it needs Linq):

```
[Test]
public void DivisorsTest()
{   
    int n = 0; 
    int expected = 0; //error
    IEnumerable<Integer> actual;
    actual = Science.Mathematics.NumberTheoryFunctions.Divisors(n);
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.All(x => x != expected));
}
```

Comment: expected is not just zero value that was just examble , the nexttest case will be when expected is the values 3,9,12,15

Comment: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Science.Integer' and 'Science.Integer[]'

Comment: Yes, my example is intended for testing the "actual" array against a single integer, so I agree with you that it's not a solution. But @Thomas Levesque gave a nice workaround that should address your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also initialize expected to an empty enumerable (i.e., zero elements) like this

```
IEnumerable<int> expected = System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

[MSDN Reference for Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx)

Comment: actually i also want to test other case not just the zero case , as the return value may be more than just one value

Comment: What about having multiple tests?  One for Zero, and one for more than zero.  Just a thought.

Comment: i want excepected to be an array contain values not empty.. would you tell me how

Answer (score 0):

I often use something like that:

```
var expected = new int[] { /* expected values */ };
var actual = Science.Mathematics.NumberTheoryFunctions.Divisors(n);
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEquals(actual));
```

The drawback is that the assertion default error message isn't very descriptive:

```
Expected: True
But was: False
```

Instead, you can use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`, which gives a more detailed error message, but it's not ideal either... If you use a Linq query, the message can look like that:

```
Expected: equivalent to < 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10 >
But was:  <System.Linq.Enumerable+<WhereIterator>d__0`1[System.Int32]>
```

(at least with NUnit 2.4.8, perhaps I should upgrade to a newer version...)